# What happens to blocks if a block plugin is no longer maintained?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I have done a lot of research on the **Internet**, but I cannot find an answer to this question:

What happens to blocks if a block plugin is no longer maintained?

Let's say I use **Atomic Blocks**. What happens to **Atomic Blocks'** blocks if **Atomic Blocks** is no longer maintained?

Is there a danger that a future version of **Wordpress** will not recognize these blocks?

Thanks,

François

Comment: Yes, it's entirely possible. Another risk is security holes being discovered in them with no one to fix them.

Comment: @ceejayoz Thanks. This answers my question. I will continue to use **CSS** styles instead. It's a pity, because this takes away a lot of appeal of using blocks. Especially since the blocks provided with **WordPress** are very basic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Atomic Block has over 40,000+ Active installations! I'm not sure if it's going to be shut off soon Alos for most page builders they all use either shortcodes of their own or use native Html for their block even if Atomic is not a full-page builder it still works like one.

So the answer to your question is: If the Atomic uses native HTML all the page you build using it will remain functional, but if it does use its own shortcodes, then as soon as you deactivate it or its updates stops and WP become un-compatible with it on the future all pages that are using it will not work as they should.

Plugins updates are so important so if a plugin is not maintained anymore then there is a chance it becomes open for threats by hackers.

Comment: @mohamed-ali-o-ameur Thanks for the details. I'll check for those Block plugins using native HTML.